# How can I validation a form with AJAX in laravel with request file?

Tags: javascript, json, laravel

shere is my request codes

```
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
        'code'=>'required',
        'title'=>'required',
        'level'=>'required',
        'related'=>'required',
        'active'=>'required',
    ];
}
```

I want show the errors with AJAX. There are many solutions for this problem in the stackoverflow but none of them can solve my problem
because they describe static method to handle this problem I want use request file for putting rules and show errors in my view with AJAX
please help me

```
 var errors = data.responseJSON;
        $.each(errors, function(key, value){
            $('#' + key)
                .closest('.form-group')
                .addClass('has-error')
                .append('<span class="help-block">' + value + '</span>');
        });
```

Comment: can you please show me what you get when you send the request with invalid inputs? , because in the reference : https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#form-request-validation you can see that `If validation fails, a redirect response will be generated to send the user back to their previous location. The errors will also be flashed to the session so they are available for display. If the request was an AJAX request, a HTTP response with a 422 status code will be returned to the user including a JSON representation of the validation errors.` showing the response will help us help you more

Comment: Hi buddy. I have 422 error in network window in my browser with using laravel request but I want to reach to field names that they have errors to show suitable message to user. I made this with using Validator in laravel before but I want to use request file for handling the errors

Comment: yes I know, you got 422 error I want to know what is in the preview tab, when you click on network tab, then click on the request, then you will see tabs Headers, Preview, Response, Cookies, Timing, Tell me what you see in Preview and Response Tab, thank you

Comment: Hi buddy. I use Mozila firefox and there isn't preview tab in my browser. There are headers / cookies / params / responses / timings. In params tab _token has value and so has active field. And other fields haven't value. in response tab a JSON returned. message:"The given data was invalid." and an error object with multiple array including my fields.in each array has suitable message.So how can I show these messages to my view with using javascript ?

Comment: okay, now you can use the JSON data as you wish if you want more help please add your response as a code in your question and add the AJAX javascript code as well so I can help you more.., thank you

Comment: as you can see I edited my codes and put the js codes. I can't retrieve the message from JSON response ! please guide me to handle this problem. thank you so much.

Comment: the response will be something like that `{ error: 422, errors: [ 'code': 'code feild is required',...] }` so to parse it. it'll be something like that `errors = data.errors`. if you didn't get the idea please show me what shows up when you `console.log(data)`. thank you

Comment: thank you so much for your attention buddy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution : 
I added this codes to my Ajax :

```
$.ajax({
    url:myUrl,
    type:method,
    data : form.serialize(),
    success:function(data)
    {
        // if success run these codes
    },
    error: function(xhr){
        var data = xhr.responseJSON;
        if($.isEmptyObject(data.errors) == false) {
            $.each(data.errors, function (key, value) {
                $('#' + key)
                    .closest('.form-group')
                    .addClass('has-error')
                    .append('<span class="help-block">' + value + '</span>');
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating your Handler.php or manage to response?

My suggestion is to modify the file `App\Exceptions\Handler.php`. On the method `render()` you can add or replace with this code:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{  
    $parent = parent::render($request, $exception);

    if(!$request->is('api*'))
    {
        return $parent;
    }

    $messages = null;

    if(isset($parent->original) && isset($parent->original["errors"]))
    {
        $messages = $parent->original["errors"];
    }

    return response()->json(
        [
            'errors' => [
                'status' => 401,
                "messages" => $messages
            ]
        ], 401
    );
}
```

This code will response a json when your route is under `api`.

Comment: Hi. Could you please explain these codes? What differences between handler.php original codes and this block codes that you wrote ? I could handle my problem but without this block code, actually I couldn't see any changes on my output.